# "delete post" doesn't always show votes remaining

Tags: bug, user-interface, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I came across the following subtle inconsistency when you're given the option to delete a post (answer or question):

[image: Moderator Tools - Flagged posts]

They both show a confirmation dialog, but the delete link shows the number of votes remaining whereas the button shows the "old" message devoid of any remaining votes indication.

If possible, it would be nice to have both options do the same thing :)

Comment: And here I thought this was another complaint about my flag handling ;)

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the retag, I wouldn't have found that one ;-)